# How to delete active image in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have a bootstrap carousel and I implement two buttons, one for upload an image and the other for delete the current image show it in the carousel. I dont know how to delete the active element. Can you help me with the code of the button? Thanks so much

```
   <div class="carousel slide" id="carousel-1">
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
  {{#each contents}}
    <li data-slide-to="{{@index}}" data-target="#carousel-1" class="{{#unless @index}}active{{/unless}}"></li>
  {{/each}}
    <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-1" class="customized-indicator">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i><span> Add new</span>
    </li>
</ol>

<div class="carousel-inner">
  {{#each contents}}
    {{#carousel_active this}}
      <div class="item {{#if value.active}}active{{/if}}">
        <img alt="{{value.title.title}}" src="{{value.image.url}}">
        <div class="overlay">
          <button class="btn carousel-button">
            <i class="fa fa-exchange"></i> Replace Image
          </button>
          <button class="btn carousel-button">
            <i class="fa fa-times-circle"></i> Remove Image
          </button> 
        </div>
      </div>
    {{/carousel_active}}
  {{/each}}
</div>

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-1" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like :

```
$('.overlay .carousel-button:last-child').on('click', function(){  
     $('.item.active img').remove()     
 });
```